# What is the difference between JOIN through ON and Using in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to write a query to display the last name, department
number, and department name for all the employees.

And this my working code:

```
SELECT
    last_name,
    department_id,
    department_name
FROM
    employees
JOIN departments USING(DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

When I was trying to make the query using JOIN ON ,I faced an error saying that

> ```
>   Column 'department_id' in field list is ambiguous through this code
> ```

query using JOIN ON:

```
SELECT
    last_name,
    department_id,
    department_name
FROM
    employees
JOIN departments ON(
        employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
    )
```

I want to know why it is not working .

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: ON & USING & ON vs USING are faqs. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ambiguity should be resolved  in select clause

```
SELECT
last_name,
employees.department_id,
department_name
FROM      employees
JOIN departments USING(DEPARTMENT_ID);
```